# React Native variable not working in StyleSheet

Tags: react-native

I am learning react native and wanted to use a variable in my styles to keep things dry. I created a constant that looks like this:

```
export default {
  primary: 'black',
  accent: 'white'
}
```

then I imported it and where I use it directly in a color prop on a component it works just fine:

```
<View style={button}><Button title='reset' color={primary}/></View>
```

however when I try to use it in StyleSheets I get this error:
"Uncaught Error
Can't find variable: primary"

here is my component:

```
import React from 'react'
import colors from '../constants/colors'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

const Header = () => {
  const { header, headerTitle} = styles
  const { primary } = colors
  return (
    <View style={header}>
      <Text style={headerTitle}>Guess a Number</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 90,
    paddingTop: 36,
    backgroundColor: primary,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  headerTitle : {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 18
  }
})

export default Header
```

I did triple check to make sure the path to colors is correct.

Comment: the destructuring is inside the Header component. You either move it out or use colors.primary in StyleSheet.

Answer (score 1):

The solution ended up being that I had used destructuring in this component and the StyleSheet is outside the component scope. So I have to either destructure outside the component or use the long hand syntax colors.primary.